# Create PDF with proper format and Images in Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

Please read my scenario carefully,

I have one `UITextView` and one `UIImageView` bottom of TextView.
Each time there will be dynamic content in TextView and accordingly that, I am asking User to make a signature and it will be displayed as an image in bottom ImageView.

Now the requirement is I have to pass these details on the server along with Signature in one PDF file, So I have to create PDF file which contains both TextView text and ImageView image.

**Note: TextView is containing Html text also, so it should show in the same format in PDF also.**

**Check below Images as required and current pdfs.**

**This is required PDF**
[image: This is required PDF]

**This is current PDF**
[image: This is current PDF]

**Only Put the code which can be helpful for both HTML support and Image merge with text. Please don't show simple PDF creation as I have done it already.**

Comment: can you use library for this . so i will give you

Comment: In my opinion the best way ist to make a html/css to create the content, then put the result in in a web view. After the web view is finished loaded use the webview.printformatter to render your pdf with it. You need to use the webview print formatter for it, because the images are not getting rendered as base64 without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need a 3rd party library, Cocoa and Cocoa touch have rich PDF support.  I've stubbed you out a little start, do this in your viewController.  There may be a few small errors, Ive been using swift  for a couple  of years now but I used my  very rusty objC here because you tagged the question that way.  Let me know any problems, good luck

```
  -(NSData *)drawPDFdata{

    //  default pdf..
    // 8.5 X 11 inch @72dpi
    // = 612 x 792
    CGRect rct = {{0.0 , 0.0 } , {612.0 , 792.0}}
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, rct, nil);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();


 //textView drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(pdfContext);
    CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50.0,50.0));//this  is  just an offset for the textView drawing. You will  want to play with the values, espeecially if supporting multiple screen sizes you might tranform the scale  as well..

    [textView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]
    CGContextRestoreGState(pdfContext);


//imageView drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(pdfContext);
    CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50.0,50.0)); //this  is  just an offset for the imageView drawing. Thee same stuff applies as above..
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]
    CGContextRestoreGState(pdfContext);



//cleanup
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return pdfData;

}
```

here's a couple of  client functions to use  this  NSData

```
   //ways to use the pdf Data
-(Bool)savePDFtoPath: (NSString *)path {

    return [ [self drawPDFdata]  writeToFile:path atomically:YES] ;

}

//requires Quartz framework.. (can be  drawn straight to a UIView)
// note you MAY owe a CGPDFDocumentRelease() on the  result  of this function (sorry i've not used objC in a couple of years...)
-(CGPDFDocument *)createPDFdocument {

    NSData *data = [self  drawPDFdata];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL , data , sizeof(data) ,NULL);

    CGPDFDocument result = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider); //not sure if this is still required under ARC??  (def not in swift)

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can this generated pdf copy text？

Answer (score 1):

Try this useful third party library :

https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf

**Use this function for your problem :**

```
+ (id)createPDFWithHTML:(NSString*)HTML pathForPDF:(NSString*)PDFpath pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize margins:(UIEdgeInsets)pageMargins successBlock:(NDHTMLtoPDFCompletionBlock)successBlock errorBlock:(NDHTMLtoPDFCompletionBlock)errorBlock;
```

Comment: I have already checked this library, but it is not allowing me to use html text from TextView and also not allowing to merge signature

Comment: is signature is image ?

Comment: i already use this working fine with your scenario ....what you want to do elaborate more .?